# Carga de pagina se detiene despues de un rato

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hola mando a cargar una pagina constantemente dentro de otra con JQuery pero despues de un rato pasa esto y no responde el sition,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al borrar las cookies , del sitio y recargar todo vuelve a la normalidad, que podria hacer para evitar que esto pase, o optimizarlo??? gracias

Esto lo realizo de la siguiente manera

```
  load();

            function load() {


                $("#prueba").load("ami2.php", function() {

                        load();            

                });

            }
```

Comment: Va a ser difícil ayudarte si no proporcionas más detalles de lo que estás haciendo, con código. Por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estás haciendo muchas peticiones seguidas al servidor, deberías poner una pausa entre una y otra:

```
$("#prueba").load("ami2.php", function() {
     setTimeout(()=>{
         load(); 
    },2000); // pausa de dos segundos entre una petición y la otra.

 });
```

Comment: Hola lo que pasa es que su funcion seria como un realtime, valida solo contadores de segundo pero un software ya hecho , solo le estoy dando como soporte y mantenimiendo funciona de esa manera en otros lados pero lo tienen en un servidor local,

este esta en un server nube , y la pagina ami2.php hace consultas a otro servidor no se que pueda ser. 
aveces se me muere a los 5 segundos otras veces a los minutos.